# ajax call response not appending because of q-translate plugin

Tags: wordpress, qtranslate

I have been using q-trasnalte and event maneger plugin in my word press and there is problem with ajax call.

one ajax call is in for location search in admin which is not working.(there is result in response in ajax call but response is not appending to HTML  )

I have triend to add '?lang=' . qtrans_getLanguage()' with my ajaxurl but it is not working.

I am using 'Use Pre-Path Mode (Default, puts /en/ in front of URL)' in qtrsnalte setting.

I have already go through forum on google but it is not working.

If i disable q-translate plugin it works correctly.

Can you guide me what am i missing ?

Thank you.

Comment: are you sending action parameter while you are calling ?

Comment: yes, i am sending action parameter, i am getting response in console too..

Comment: can you check this link once http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20477664/wordpress-problems-with-qtranslate-and-ajax

Comment: above link has something to look at to solve this issue.

Comment: i have checked it, but it is not working in my case.

Comment: any error or notice you are getting while you are using this or anything else .. if u can tell me

Comment: it is interesting, there is no error or notice of plugin exist.

Comment: i wish our debug mode is ON ..  ON it if its OFF ..

Comment: yes, debug mode is on too :(

Comment: Give an example of non-working ajax request